# Centering social media icons in footer of website

Tags: css, icons, footer

Im fairly new to the world of CSS and HTML, so my apologies in advanced.

I am having a problem getting my social media icons to center themselves at the bottom of my website. 
They are sitting bottom heavy rather in the middle of the footer.
Attached is screen shot of the issue and the code behind it.

[Image of current footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny305.png)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.page-footer {
  background-color: #F06D71;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<footer class="page-footer">
  <ul>
    <img class="responsive-img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <img class="responsive-img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    <img class="responsive-img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </ul>
</footer>
```

I've attempted to add "padding-bottom" to the style sheet, but the icons just get smaller rather moving up a few pixels.

Any advice or any terms i should look into?

Regards

Comment: "align: center" does not work for you?

Comment: that is deprecated, you use tex-align:center; now

Comment: You should write your code in your question, not an image of it.

Comment: I tried helping you creating a code snippet, please modify it with your css to be as precise as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flexbox:

```
.page-footer{
 display:flex;
}

.page-footer ul{
 align-items:center;
}
```

This will center the icons vertically inside the footer.  You also should have the images wrapped in `<li>` tags within the list as list items.  If you also want to nicely center them vertically you could add display: inline-block to the list elements and text-align center to its parent, the unordered list.  So the final code would be:

```
.page-footer{
  display:flex;
}

.page-footer ul{
  justify-content:center;
  text-align:center;
}

.page-footer ul li{
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

Also one more thing I noticed, you have added the same ID to all three images.  An ID should be a unique identifier and only used on one element.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://howtocenterincss.com/) is a great tool to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

For the class of `.page-footer` add a property of `display: table`;

Then wrap your image tags in a `<div>` and assign the property of `display: table-cell` to the div and also the property of `vertical-align: middle;`.

Doing this will vertically align anything inside that div to the middle of the element.

See this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkskp7kL/) that I made as a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always obvious even for an experienced developer. If you want to have just images in your footer you could just do padding. Also you have missing `<li>` inside `<ul>` tag.
Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .footer-list-item {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .footer-list {
      padding: 50px 0;
      background: pink;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="footer">
    <ul class="footer-list">
      <li class="footer-list-item"><img width="50" src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg" alt="Welcome to JS Bin"></li>
      <li class="footer-list-item"><img width="50" src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg" alt="Welcome to JS Bin"></li>
      <li class="footer-list-item"><img width="50" src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg" alt="Welcome to JS Bin"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSBin [link](https://jsbin.com/yotewiroza/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: A little late on this response. But THANK YOU, this fixed my problem! I read up on flexbox on css tricks. And then saw this and used your jsbin link along with my codepen stuff and it worked! :)